# mysql LOAD DATA INFILE of csv from python (Not Working)

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

After some data manipulation I store two columns in a txt file in a csv format as following:

result.txt ->

```
id,avg
0,38.0
1,56.5
3,66.5
4,48.666666666666664
```

then I store the data in a table, which is where i find trouble, i tried running a .sql query that stores the data successfully, but executing the same query from python doesnt seem to work for some reason.

python code->

```
.
.
.
open('C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/result.txt', 'w').write(res)
print(res)

try:
    with mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user='root',
        password='tt',
        database="dp",
    ) as connection:
        clear_table_query = "drop table if exists test_db.marks;"
        create_table_query = '''
        create table test_db.marks (
    id  varchar(255) not null,
    avg varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (id)
);
'''
# droping the table and recreating it works fine

        add_csv_query = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/result.txt' INTO TABLE marks FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;"

        print(add_csv_query) # query is printed correctly

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(clear_table_query)
            cursor.execute(create_table_query)
            cursor.execute(add_csv_query)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test_db.marks;") # this produces -> Unread result found
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    print(e)

connection.close()
```

Comment: *ENCLOSED BY '\"'* - where?? use OPTIONAL.

Comment: removing it completely works fine, as long as I run the query from ```.sql``` file, but for some reason executing it through python doesn't

Comment: Have you tried checking the MyQql log to see what transaction is received; and if so, the engine error? There is always a means to trace a problem further - my advice (for anyone) is always to work on finding the trace, and not as much jumping to the solution.